# Facebook from chrome extension - getLoginStatus failing

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, facebook-graph-api, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a chrome extension which should work with facebook but I'm failing at the beginning: the authorization

The following code

```
<html>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: 'xxx', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: false});

};
(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.type = 'text/javascript';
    e.src = 'http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
     FB.init({appId: 'xxx', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});

         /* All the events registered */
         FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
             // do something with response
                document.write('Not written out');
             //login();
         });

         FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
             // do something with response
        document.write('Not written out');
             //logout();
         });

         arpa = FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        document.write('Not written out');
             if (response.session) 
             {
                 // logged in and connected user, someone you know
            document.write('Not written out');
                 //login();
             }
         else
             { 
                 document.write('Not written out');
             }
         }, true);
document.write(arpa); // writes out - 'undefined'
document.write('This is written out');
     };
</script>
</html>
```

isn't working since FB.getLoginStatus function seems not to return anything nor call the callback function and nothing is printed out.

But isn't a wrong line either because the program continue and writes out "undefined" and the last document.write

What could cause this? Logging out from fb don't solve the problem either.

Comment: Where are you using this code? In a background_page? In a popup?

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand the above solution.

It is impossible to use the js sdk to authenticate with Chrome Extensions. You should use Oauth and directly connect via http calls.

This is how I see chrome fb apps do it when I look at their source. Here is an example:

https://github.com/zuzara/facebook-connect-for-chrome-extension

Comment: _“It is impossible to use the js sdk to authenticate with Chrome.”_ – you should probably add that this applies to Chrome _extensions_, not web pages displaying in Chrome in general … otherwise someone might misunderstand it.